# Problem converting the timestamp 1426593600000 to a date

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, date-time

I am trying to get some calendar items based on the `StartTime` field.

I've done this:

```
/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/MyAgenda?$filter=StartTime%20gt%20datetime%272015-03-16T19:00:00Z%27
```

This show me the correct result. The problem is that when I am trying to convert this date in JavaScript I am getting the wrong date.

In Edit page of the list I see the StartTime field like this:

Start Time - 3/17/2015 12:00 PM

Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp in your question is called Epoch Date. It is the number of seconds that have elapsed since January 1, 1970 (midnight UTC/GMT), not counting leap seconds (in ISO 8601: 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z).

To convert this you can use JavaScript Date object.

You can do that using following code

```
var myDate = new Date(1426593600000);
alert(myDate.toGMTString()+"<br>"+myDate.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: This way it is showing the correct hour. Could you please let me know how can I get the day hours, minutes etc? When I try to do so, It gets the wrong value... Thanks!

Comment: `var myDate = new Date(1426593600000); alert(myDate.getHours()); alert(myDate.getMinutes());` for more on date object http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: This way it is showing a wrong value. If you take a look at the myDate.toGMTString() you will see that the hour is 12

Comment: Ok in that case you can use `getUTCHours()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method.

```
var startdate = new Date(#your date); // #your date = startdate
      var a_p = "";
      var curr_hour = startdate.getHours();
      if (curr_hour < 12) {
          a_p = "am";
      }
      else {
          a_p = "pm";
      }
      if (curr_hour == 0) {
          curr_hour = 12;
      }
      if (curr_hour > 12) {
          curr_hour = curr_hour - 12;
      }
      var curr_min = startdate.getMinutes();
      curr_min = curr_min + "";

      if (curr_min.length == 1) {
          curr_min = "0" + curr_min;
      }
      startdate = [(startdate.getMonth() + 1).padLeft(), startdate.getDate().padLeft(), startdate.getFullYear()].join('/') + ' ' + [curr_hour, curr_min].join(':') + ' '+ [a_p] ;
```

it will give you the result in this format:
10/02/2014 10:30 am ie mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm in 12 hour format